Combining words to make a name/nickname
I traveled to Japan last summer, and I was lucky enough to climb Mt Fuji and see the sunrise from the summit. During this trip I had given my jacket to my wife and thus didn't actually have much in the way of warmth. One of the people I met at the summit made a joke about me not being dressed warmly enough for how cold it was, and called me a mountain fool. I am still learning Japanese and not quite familiar enough with the ins and outs of the naming conventions. I wanted to ask if there's a way to combine "yama" and "baka" into a name/nickname to help commemorate that very special memory. I have also seen "mountain fool" translated as yama no baka. I have also seen somewhat mixed information on the rudeness of the term "baka" and didn't want to incorporate a slur, but other information seemed to say it was a pretty varied word with varied degrees of rudeness based on context. I appreciate any help and clarification.

Maybe [山]{やま}[愚]{ぐ}[者]{しゃ} (Yamagusya) would sound better / more literary :) .

Someone calls himself 山馬鹿 and this sounds OK as a nickname. There are words like 釣り馬鹿 (釣り being fishing). 馬鹿 may be written in katakana as バカ.

山バカ does work as a nickname but it's more like "mountain maniac" (in the sense of "hardcore mountaineer") rather than "mountain idiot/fool". Which connotation do you want?

@naruto The context of the situation definitely was a joking mockery of me being poorly insulated for the cold. I'm leaning towards whatever captures that connotation best, and of course not wanting to be disrespectful. The name being a playful jab at me is fine and humorous, but I definitely don't want to use a slur or culturally offensive term.

See also Differences between words for "idiot", The difference between 愚かな and 愚かしい. [愚]{ぐ}[者]{しゃ} mentioned earlier is also used in Tarot.

@Arfrever thank you. That name works very well! Trying to fill in the knowledge gaps and pay appropriate respect to a very special memory climbing my first mountain.

As long as you use it to refer to yourself, "baka" itself is not such a strong word that you need to worry about offending someone. However, there is an issue which you might not have noticed. "Baka" in Japanese actually works as a suffix meaning "enthusiast"! From this dictionary entry:

馬鹿

fervent enthusiast; nut; person singularly obsessed with something​ Usually written using kana alone, Slang, usu. in compounds


For example, we say 釣り馬鹿 (tsuri baka) or 柔道馬鹿 (judo baka) to refer to someone who is obsessed with fishing or judo. Saying 山馬鹿 (yama baka) also usually implies "mountain fanatic", which may be fine as a nickname but is probably not what you want now. Directly combining two nouns is a valid way of forming a compound noun in Japanese, but in this specific case, it doesn't work as you expect.
One easy way to fix this is to simply stop using 馬鹿 as a suffix. How about saying 山の馬鹿 (yama no baka, "fool on the mountain") or 山上の馬鹿野郎 (sanjo no baka-yaro, "goddamn idiot on the mountain top")? Since there is の (a noun-linking particle), they're a bit longer, but these phrases effectively convey the humorous tone in "mountain fool". I'm not sure what you really want to do with this "nickname", but these expressions are suitable at least for photo captions in albums or on Instagram.

This was extremely helpful. Thank you very much! It's sort of intended as a screen name or just tag for things. Nothing too serious. I was excited about the idea of using it or some contraction of it as an avatar for online functions and whatnot. Not to inconvenience you more than I already have, but are there homophones or sort of puns that shorten it while maintaining a similar meaning? The way Izuku Midoriya's name is constructed comes to mind and the extra meanings of his nickname Deku as both a representation of "you can do it" and being "useless as a wooden doll"

@RobertJohnson I thought the name was for describing your Mount Fuji episode, but if not, wouldn't any name do? None of the names I mentioned are particularly long. Anyway, suggesting creative names is not the scope of this site.

I apologize for the miscommunication. I wasn't trying to outsource the creative labor just asking about that particular aspect of the language. I may have phrased it poorly. The Deku example just being the best way I knew to describe the concept I'd seen. I appreciate all the help you've provided. Thank you.
